# Bootstrap carousel image sliding effect and time duration change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using bootstrap carousel. I want to change the transition timing and effect to 2s ease. i overridden it with following css

```
.carousel-inner> .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}
```

It is working But the problem is the first image disappears before the next on reaches the end

I have given the screen shot exactly what happening in my website [image]

Comment: Is this live somewhere? Or can you create a fiddle?

Comment: its in my website.. as u can see the second image still half way but image previous image is already disappeared..0.6s is default time

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: i'm still on localhost

Comment: Well, you're basically asking us to guess what's wrong here. My guess is, look at the other timing in your css. You changed one value and it threw things out of sync.